# D3 - drawing multiple shapes

Tags: d3.js

I am defining coordinates for two parallelogram shapes, but only first one is getting rendered:

```
var shapeCoords = [
            [[10, 10], [100, 20], [100, 100], [10, 90]],
            [[10, 110], [100, 120], [100, 200], [10, 190]]
          ];

for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i+=10){ 
    path = svg.selectAll('path').data([shapeCoords[i*0.1]], function(d){        
        return [i, i+1, i+2, i+3]; //giving keys 0,1,2,3 and 10,11,12,13 repectively for each loop
        })
        .enter().append('svg:path').attr('d', function(d){
                        return line(d) + 'Z'
                        })
        .//some styles,etc;              
}//end for
```

As per d3 cocepts of selectAll, data, enter, if I assign different keys, then it should have been rendered. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need loop through data array for data join, d3 do it for us.

```
svg.selectAll('path').data(shapeCoords)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', function(d){
    return line(d) + 'Z'
  })
```

Comment: Please tell me if the code uploaded not work, thanks!

Comment: I am looking for an explanation about why my code is not working. And taking all points for different shapes wont work - it will create different shapes with a  line connecting the shapes, which I don't want

Comment: The second time, you bind data, there is no need to `enter`

Comment: you mean to say path.append('svg:path') instead path.enter().append('svg:path') ? I tried this, but with no change

Comment: After `enter` and `append`, there is no need for do the same thing the second time, because the dom of `path` are already there.

Comment: Not clear, can you please write the complete modified code for it.

Comment: Okay I understood what you mean to say. It didn't even required selectAll though. But it is more about solving any problem, rather understanding the D3 logic. I was learning d3 and thought to experiment with key function. And the question is about that.